# Lua idioms compiled in one place

Tags: lua, iphone-wax

I am using Lua for some of my apps. I am looking for a central repository of Lua idioms because I don't want to write C in Lua.

A few examples I've come across are:

```
x = x or v
```

This sets a default value for x if it is not already set.

Another is

```
x, y = y, x
```

to exchange two variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of useful snippets and idioms in these links:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/SampleCode

http://www.luafaq.org

Answer (score 2):

[Lua Patterns, Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89523/lua-patterns-tips-and-tricks) here on Stack Overflow is also very good read.

Comment: Well it may well have been, but it was blockwarted.

Comment: This is a dead link :(

Comment: Formatting didn't survive well, but:   https://web.archive.org/web/20100609035807/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89523/lua-patterns-tips-and-tricks

Answer (score 1):

Try http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaDirectory - that and the Lua manual/PiL are probably your two best resources in this regard.

- [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/)
- [Programming in Lua, 1st Edition](http://www.lua.org/pil/) (The first edition is available online freely. The second you can buy, though the third edition -- for 5.2 -- should be coming soon.)

Comment: If you mention the Manual, you should mention PiL as well. :-)

Comment: My first reaction to that comment was to think amusedly "wait, you mean PiL isn't the Lua manual?" ;)